# How to make SharePoint PeopleEditor WebControl Serializable? C#, SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, serialization, sharepoint-2007, peoplepicker

I would like to basically extend `PeopleEditor` to make it `Serializable` in order to store in `ViewState` because it is created dynamically and I need it during `PostBack`.

I have this:

```
[Serializable]
public class PeopleEditor : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor, ISerializable
{
}
```

But am not sure where to go from there. Does anyone have some input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this way. I would recommend to store only the count and values of people editor control which are created dynamically and upon postback create the count number of people editor control and restore the values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created them dynamically based on SP permission groups. I would like to note the changes to the PeopleEditors, e.g. Added or Removed users. Is there a way to grab the values of the boxes before the postback after the button click? That seems to be what you are saying but im not aware of which function to write which can do this. Thanks.